# How do I get prompt colours and auto-complete on 18.04 for a new user created with useradd?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, auto-completion, prompt

I use [Tilix](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix), which is imo one of the best VTE based terminal emulators for Linux. If I create an Ubuntu 16.04 image on DigitalOcean, connect to it via SSH and then configure a new user (as below), everything is fine. I get highlighted the path, directories, username, etc.:

```
useradd -m username
passwd username
usermod -a -G sudo username
su username
```

**But** if I do the same with an 18.04 image the highlighting doesn't work and also autocomplete and keyboard arrow, etc don't work. Why is this? And how can I change the behavior so that it works like in 16.04?

**EDIT:**
bash completion is installed and auto-complete also works if I am logged in as root (even though without the highlighting). But as soon as I `su username` autocomplete is also gone